# How can I get the java output from right to left?

Tags: java

This is my code

```
int z = n;
System.out.print(n + " - ");
for (int i=1; i<11; i++) {
    if (z%10!=4 && z%10!=0 && z!=4) {
        z *= 2;
        System.out.print(z + " - ");
    } else if ((z%10==4 || z%10==0) && z!=4) {
        z /= 10;
        System.out.print(z + " - ");
    } 
}
```

and my output:

```
1 - 2 - 4 - 
2 - 4 - 
3 - 6 - 12 - 24 - 2 - 4 - 
5 - 10 - 1 - 2 - 4 - 
7 - 14 - 1 - 2 - 4 -
```

Is there a way I can get it starting with the 4s the other way around?
Like this:

```
- 4 - 2 - 1
- 4 - 2
- 4 - 2 - 24...
```

Comment: Try to save them in an `array` and later `reverse` the array and get **output**

Comment: Or use a recursive function instead of a for loop.

Comment: @JoopEggen Is this not a recursive function? I thought it is one by using z*=2 and z/=10

Comment: where does it call itself?

Comment: @EgonCarter added an ugly solution, `grec` calls itself, giving a new value. If one prints the passed `z` after the recursive call, the output is reversed. A _recursive_  function calls itself, doing just a small bit of work itself. recursion = routing back to oneself. I think that was the reason for this task. Or you were just taught about stacks or such.

Answer (score 0):

As I think this is homework I'll give a dirty solution:

- f: the original function
- g: the reversing function
- grec: the recursive part, after it call print the current value

So after the recursive call with a changed `z`:

```
    int[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 5, 7};
    for (int n : nums) {
        f(n);
        g(n);
        System.out.println("====================");
    }
```

and

```
private static void f(int n) {
    int z = n;
    System.out.print(n + " - ");
    for (int i=1; i<11; i++) {
        if (z%10!=4 && z%10!=0 && z!=4) {
            z *= 2;
            System.out.print(z + " - ");
        } else if ((z%10==4 || z%10==0) && z!=4) {
            z /= 10;
            System.out.print(z + " - ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}

private static void g(int n) {
    grec(n, 0);
    System.out.println(" - " + n);
}

private static void grec(int z, int i) {
    if (i >= 11) {
         return;
    }
    if (z % 10 != 4 && z % 10 != 0 && z != 4) {
        z *= 2;
    } else if ((z % 10 == 4 || z % 10 == 0) && z != 4) {
        z /= 10;
    } else {
        grec(z, i + 1);
        return;
    }
    grec(z, i + 1);
    System.out.print(" - " + z);
}
```

Better code is not to change the input `z` but do `grec(z*2, i + 1);` and so on.
Try that to receive better points.